# How to use foreign key to get related objects?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have a `person` which could have many `images`. 
I would like to use like this: `person.image[x].image` to retrieve my `image` address. How can I associate using `foreign key` a `person` with their `images` ? And access their `images` using a `person` object ?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = CharField(max_length=1, choices=GenderChoices, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Image(models.Model):
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
    itype = CharField(max_length=1, choices=ImageChoices)
    image = ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.path
```

Answer (score 1):

`person.image_set.all()` is one way, and if needed you can also filter through the images of a person for a given query, e.g. `persom.image_set.filter(...)`, and if you just want the count, `person.image_set.count()`

You can read more on how to query for related objects here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects